# "Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found" error. after removing fabric from build.gradle

Tags: android, firebase, capacitor, ionic-react

in my ionic react project android version build using capacitor, i followed the steps of removing all the fabric and replacing them with crashlytics

reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

the build command:

```
ionic cap copy android
ionic cap open android
```

now I am just getting the error when building:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found.
```

here's my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
 
apply from: "variables.gradle"

ext {
    var = '4.1.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here's my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // firebaseCrashlytics {
            //     nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            // }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

version reference:

```
android studio: 1.4
android gradle plugin version: 4.1.1
gradle version: 6.6
```

Comment: when installing firebase don't install "cordova-plugin-firebase" if you are using react with ionic, it will create this error! fixed after removed

Comment: I'm new to Ionic and I am getting this same issue after installing firebase and trying to open the app in Android Studio.  What did you use to undo the 'cordova-plugin-firebase' install and what did you use to reinstall firebase?

Comment: i use npm 'uninstall cordova-plugin-firebase'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when installing firebase don't install "cordova-plugin-firebase" if you are using react with ionic, it will create this error! fixed after removed

Comment: what to do while using ionic? 
I got same error and couldn't solve it, Please help

Comment: `npm uninstall cordova-plugin-firebase` try that, it's a compatability issue

Comment: haha thank you for an answer, but the app was built and it is already on the market :D